# css and js files are not loading in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to include CSS and JS files in WordPress custom plugin. This is what i have done. I have included files like this but i am unable to locate why files are not including in WordPress.

```
function wppd_scripts(){

wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS', plugins_url( 'css/myCSS.css', __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true); // addition of 'get_template_directory_uri()   
wp_enqueue_script('jquery',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'js/jquery.js',array ( 'jquery','jquery.min' ), '', false);                        
}
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wppd_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work when two of them have the same handle. Try this:

```
function wppd_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS.css', __FILE__ ) );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapcss', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/bootstrap.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'/js/jquery.js',array ( 'jquery','jquery.min' ), '', false);                        
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wppd_scripts');
```

Comment: nope.. it didn't worked for me. anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot the trailing slahes.